How to switch to i3 and back without leaving session?
Consider a system with the default Ubuntu 22.04. After installing i3 using
sudo apt install i3

I can use i3 by logging out, switching to i3 on the login screen and then logging in again.
Is it possible to do the same without having to log out that is, to keep all the windows/programs open? (And if so, how?)
The reason I'm asking is that on the one hand certain (GUI) programs are harder to use (at least for me) in i3, on the other hand when someone else is using the computer who doesn't know i3, it is next to impossible for them to use it. Therefore it would be nice to have an option to switch to the default Ubuntu desktop when needed.
